# Do they wash the decorative pillowcases?

Tags: hotels, hygiene

There are many pillows on the bed in many hotels (six or more), do they wash all pillowcases including the decorative ones? I want to hear from an insider.

Comment: I don't think there's anyone inside the pillow but I'm just an outsider.

Comment: I think that our question is more along the lines of when do hotels change out the pillowcases. Because I'm pretty sure that linen that is changed out is washed, and not simply transferred to another room.

Comment: It may depend on the hotel. I've been to hotels where it is clear that even the bedsheets have not been changed but then, they weren't places that give you 6 pillows (uh, I left and checked in somewhere better).

Comment: I doubt it, at least in most hotels. I don't put my face on any but the white ones. Rumor is the top covers on the bed don't get cleaned that all often either (let alone the decorative bands). If you snoop in the halls while they are cleaning the other rooms you can see what the cleaning folks put in their bins- it's usually entirely white stuff (towels, pillowcases and sheets).